# How can I get title of current active link in Woocommerce nav

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When a user logs in, he is taken to the `/my-account/` page in WooCommerce. With the help of a hook, I display 4 links there Orders, Addresses, Account Details, and Log Out.

I need to output the active link title. How can i do this? By default, the `/my-account/` address should display the title Dashboard.

```js
<?php

$page_title = '';

if (is_account_page()) {
    $page_title = 'Dashboard';
} elseif (is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' )) {
    $page_title = '1';
} elseif (is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' )) {
    $page_title = '2';
} elseif (is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' )) {
    $page_title = '3';
}

?>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="woocommerce-wrapper">
    <div class="woocommerce-wrapper__title">
    <h2><?php echo $page_title; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="woocommerce-wrapper__content">
      <?php
            /**
             * My Account navigation.
             *
             * @since 2.6.0
             */
            do_action('woocommerce_account_navigation'); ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">
          <?php
                /**
                 * My Account content.
                 *
                 * @since 2.6.0
                 */
                do_action('woocommerce_account_content');
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Start by checking what _conditional tags_ are available in WordPress in general, and WooCommerce in particular. https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags, https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please tell me, I have an Order page and I do the check as shown in the example, but I still get "Dashboard"

Comment: "is_account_page() - Returns true on the customer’s account pages." - so that why you're getting dashboard, I suppose. Those endpoints you are checking are probably considered part of that - so change the order of the conditions, and check for those first.

Comment: I tried to change the order and displayed only one endpoint, but still the title was not displayed

Comment: Where are you executing this? Quote from the WC documentation page above: _"Note: You can only use conditional query tags after the `posts_selection` action hook in WordPress (the `wp` action hook is the first one through which you can use these conditionals). For themes, this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are using it in the body of functions.php."_

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just using wrong endpoints here. Those are the endpoints for the checkout process, here are basic endpoints for my-account page:

- **Orders**: `orders`
- **Addresses**: `edit-address`
- **Account** details: `edit-account`
- **Logout**: there is probably no need, since you'd get redirected immediately

You can check (print) current WC endpoint name like this:

```
echo WC()->query->get_current_endpoint();
```

**Note**: For the dashboard page, keep using `is_account_page()` function, as the `get_current_endpoint()` is empty for the dashboard.